# Swift LayoutSubviews moving all subviews every user interaction

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I apologize if this question has been already addressed, but I cannot find it.

I thought it would be simple enough to animate a UIImageView from offscreen onto the screen at certain points in my program.  So I created the UIImageView and coded it up, but am getting a lot of strange behaviour.  I have narrowed it down to the fact that layoutSubviews is getting called every user interaction (every button press) and it is resetting the size and location of all my items.  I am using auto layout for every screen item save this one, so that is fine for the things I want auto layed out.  But this one item is constantly being moved back to it's starting location.  I proved it this way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("viewDidLoad")

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
    print(image.center)
    image.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth / 2, image.bounds.height / -2)
    print(image.center)
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    print("viewWillLayoutSubviews")
    print(image.center)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    print("viewDidLayoutSubviews")
    print(image.center)
}
```

This is the result I get:

```
viewDidLoad
(294.0, 228.0)
(160.0, -64.0)
viewWillLayoutSubviews 
(160.0, -64.0) 
viewDidLayoutSubviews 
(294.0, 228.0)
```

I don't have any constraints attached to this one view.  Thoughts?  I guess I could store the location and constantly move it around manually, but I'm sure there is a switch somewhere that turns off the autolayout for specific items.  I just can't find it.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Did you implement layoutSubviews then, or are you still in fact leaving it to auto layout?  It seems to me that you just thought you were doing it, but auto layout is still laying out this view - whether or not you specified constraints

Answer (score 1):

The image must have `autoresizingMasks` that are getting translated into constraints.

Disable it by doing this:

`image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Except I had to set image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true, which makes no sense.  This seems to do the opposite of what one would expect intuitively.  So now all my other items (which have constraints) move around as I would expect.  This item (which has no constraints) now stays put when I programatically move it.